# How to make a Loading Progress bar when form submit goes to one page to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page form.php whenever i fill the form and click on submit button it's go to code.php and then show the result on another page named ipo.php

i want to show a Loading progressbar in between form.php to ipo.php

plz anyone help me ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Page always loading from up to down. Knowing this, we can construct an architecture of loader

The first step, we create loader div that will be an overlay over all layers of a website. When site loading, we will see loader. As for your question, you must create this div on pages form.php and ipo.php. On the page form.php, you can add CSS attribute "display: none"

```
<div id="loader" style="position: fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height: 100%; background: url('loader.gif') center center #efefef"></div>
```

The second step, we must hide the loader when the page already loaded. At this step, we use the jQuery method $.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#loader').hide();
})
```

The third step, we must intercept handler of clicking to link at form.php, and show the loader before the page is unloaded

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('form').submit(function() 
    {
        $('#loader').show();
    }) 
})
```

As result, we have small jquery function for showing the loader, when the user submits the form at form.php and redirect to ipo.php

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#loader').hide();

    $('form').submit(function() 
    {
        $('#loader').show();
    }) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For progress bar take a look at this:[REF](http://www.w3bees.com/2013/10/file-upload-with-progress-bar.html)

You can put `code.php` int the action of that form in `form.php`. To load `ipo.php` you have to add a success in ajax like

```
success: function(data){
   $("#place you want to load").load("ipo.php");
}
```

there are other solutions/plugins available for this too.